# Is there a way to map a list of integers to a unique number or a unique hash?

Tags: arrays, performance, hash, integer, comparison

The permutation of the list of integers should also be preserved in the hash -- i.e., lists containing the same numbers in a different order should have different hashes.

One way to do this would be to concatenate the list of integers into a string, but this could be an expensive comparison test if the list is massive.

**Context**: If I already have 5 large arrays 'analyzed' and hashed away, I would be able to quickly check whether an incoming array is new or not.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

"In mathematics, the pigeonhole principle states that if n items are put into m containers, with n > m, then at least one container must contain more than one item"

It is certainly possible to create a unique number, its just that its hilariously huge.

Consider

```
[1,2,3]
```

A simple list, but to make sure we have enough holes for our pigeons, we would need to have space for the largest integer in each slot, so assuming 4 bytes per item, we would need a 12 byte integer to store the hash uniquely, or ~3.4028237e+38 different values. And that's only 3 integers.

No, an efficient hash is rarely unique, but a good hash is unlikely to have collisions for similar values.

To answer your question about checking for existence, consider the following:

If you have an array of n items, in order to hash it, you need to take n steps. In order to check for existence, you need, at worst, n steps to check each item in turn.

In either case, you are going to be spending about the same amount time comparing arrays.

Answer (score -1):

An array structure seems to be a perfect choice where the index differentiate between elements, or you can use a list of elements where an element has an index value assigned to just before insertion.

Never use a String as a list structure, because it has it's own properties, like immutability (in the case of Java).